# Access submenus in wordpress panel

Tags: javascript, wordpress, panel

I'm using WordPress 3.3.2. version. When i kept mouse over left side panel of wordpress panel, (i.e.) Dashboard, Posts, Media, Links, Pages etc, i couldn't access sub menus (i.e.) All Posts, Add New, Categories, Tags etc. If i disable Java Script, it is working well.

Can any one please help me to resolve this problem? As i'm new to wordpress, i don't know where to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to formulate a complete answer. You need to do some troubleshooting.

The error is most likely being caused by a mis-behaving plugin queuing a JavaScript script file that contains bug(s). Try disabling plugins in Wordpress one-by-one until the admin menu is functional again. Once you've isolated the misbehaving plugin try asking about the plugin on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. Be sure to post any error messages you encounter.

Comment: i deactivated all the plugins, but problem remains as it is

Comment: i can't able to expand / collapse modules

Comment: You'll need to do some JavaScript debugging. Try using Chrome's developer tools and looking for any JavaScript errors: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console  - the errors will show up in the console as red text.

Comment: Thanks, I found out my mistake. I blocked some scripts in functions.php. once i removed, its working well.